# Drawing a Bitmap using DrawImage

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, bitmap, drawing

I have a little prolem drawing a bitmap to the screen, i tried using the way that's shown on the MSDN library, it partially works but they didn't really give a good example there, just specyfying you need the PaintEventHandler.

So that is my code:

```
public class UI {
   public static void DrawTexture(string path, int x, int y, PaintEventArgs e) {
       Bitmap BM = new Bitmap(path);
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(BM, x, y);
   }
}
```

Now this should work, but the problem comes when calling the function:

```
UI.DrawTexture("somepic.png", 1,1, /* What to put in here? */);
```

I also tried using it in a form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, PaintEventArgs p) {
    UI.DrawTexture("somepic.png", 1,1, p);
}
```

And this gives me an error while debugging: "No overload for Form1_Load matches delegate System.EventHandler."

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No overload for Form1_Load matches delegate System.EventHandler."

Form_Load's delegate function is this (It doesn't have a parameter called "PaintEventArgs":

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //Your codes here……
}
```

So now please put into Form_Paint event:

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
UI.DrawTexture("somepic.png", 1,1, e);
        }
```